# When the derived (commutator) subgroup is in the center

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

I have the following problem in group theory from a previous exam in a college course which stumped me:

> Let $ G $ be a group such that $ G/Z(G) $ is abelian. We are asked to show that for any fixed odd $m$ the set $G^m=\{g^m | g \in G\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$

The fact that $ G/Z(G)   $ is abelian implies that the commutators (all elements of the form $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ for $ x,y\in G  $) are in the center of $ G $ meaning they commute with all elements of $ G $. This is all I could work out with the problem. The normality of the set $ G^m  $ is trivial as is showing it's closed to inverses, but how do I show it is closed under products? I thought about constructing a group homomorphism whose kernel is the set $ G^m $ but cannot figure out what such a homomorphism might look like? Why odd not even? This is where I am stuck and cannot work out a solution at all, so I obviously cannot show it is a subgroup. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: in a nilpotent group with class at most $2$ we have

$$(xy)^m = x^my^m [y,x]^{m(m-1)/2}.$$
Also, the map $[\cdot,x]$ from $G$ to $G'$ is a group homomorphism for every $x \in G$.

Comment: thank you very much for this but is there a more elementary way of approaching the problem? In our course, we did not study nilpotent groups and the class of a group at all. And even after reading the definition I did not understand how to show that our group is nilpotent of class at most 2.

Comment: thanks again but I would require further assistance even after your hint.

Comment: and I do not see how to prove $$ (xy)^m = x^my^m[y,x]^{m(m-1)/2} $$

Comment: A nilpotent group of class at most $2$ is just a group in which all commutators lie in $Z(G)$ - you don't really need to know that to answer this question.  But you do need to prove  that $(xy)^m = x^my^m[y,x]^{m(m-1)/2}$ (where $[y,x] = y^{-1}x^{-1}yx$). You can do that by induction on $m$.

Comment: Then to finish the proof, note that this equality implies $x^my^m = (xy[y,x]^{-(m-1)/2})^m$ - this is where you need to assume that $m$ is odd.